Stability of fixed points of this map (Ising chain)
The context (although not so relevant) is that of block spin procedure applied to a Ising chain with Hamiltonian (nearest neighbor interactions)
$$H=-J\sum_i \sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}-h\sum_i\sigma_i.$$
After performing the block spin transformation with scaling parameter $b=2$, the following map$^{(*)}$ arises
\begin{align}
&x'=x\frac{(1+y)^2}{(x+y)(1+xy)}\\
&y'=y\frac{x+y}{1+xy}
\end{align}
where$^{(**)}$
$$x=\mathrm{e}^{-4J}, y=\mathrm{e}^{-2h}$$
There is also another parameter but it is not really relevant as $x'$ and $y'$ do not depend on it. Let's consider the fixed points of this 2D flow. Some algebra reveals that, ignoring the origin, we have $(x^\ast,y^\ast)=(0,1)$ and $(x^\ast,y^\ast)=(1,y^\ast)$ (the line $x=1$ as fixed points). To analyze stability, I computed the Jacobian matrix and evaluated it at the fixed point. For $(0,1)$, I get the diagonal Jacobian matrix
$$J(0,1)=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$
and according to the determinant-trace classification of fixed points (cf e.g. this answer), this point is unstable because $$\Delta>0, \tau>\sqrt{4\Delta}$$
(where $\Delta$ and $\tau$ are respectively the determinant and the trace).
The problem arises with the line of fixed points. Let's consider $J(1,y)$. A quick computation reveals that
$$J(1,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
y\frac{1-y}{1+y} & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
In this case we have zero determinant and positive trace, which according to the classification above corresponds to an unstable line. Both ref. 1 and ref. 2 state it is a line of stable fixed points or equivalently that it's a sink, not a source as I've found. Can you tell me where whether my argument is flawed and where?

References

Statistical Mechanics, K. Huang. Wiley, 2ed, 1987. Chapter 18, section 18.2.
This, Section 6.
If the link doesn't work, here's the wayback machine link


$^{(*)}$
The prime denotes the variable after one step. It's not a derivative! Think of it as $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ if you prefer this notation.
$^{(**)}$
Ref.1 uses the variables $u=\mathrm{e}^{-J}$ and $v=\mathrm{e}^{-h}$. The ones above make the computations easier to work out.

Yes it is zero. That's what I meant! Just a slip-up. Edited.

The question you link is for $x'=Ax$ as a system of differential equations, not $f(x)=Ax$ as an iterated linear transformation. I'm dubious you can transpose results from the former setting to the latter.

This is the case of discrete maps, not ODE, correct. You are suggesting that a different classification would apply to a fixed point in this case. It might be the issue. I'm not very familiar with these topics.

The chapter found here provides the classification for nonlinear stability analysis. But the case of interest here (eigenvalues $0,1$) is noted as a marginal one for which linear stability analysis isn't really sufficient.

Before I begin, I'll make a comment on domain: Negative values of $x$ and $y$, while interesting mathematically, correspond to imaginary values of the real parameters $J,K$ and will not be considered further. I will also not dwell upon the cases $x=0$ and $y=0$, as these instead converge to the fixed points $(0,1)$ and $(0,0)$ respectively. Hence I'll only look at $x,y>0$ here; this has the obvious consequence that $x',y'>0$.
To start the analysis, note that the map for $x'$ can be written as
$$x'=x\frac{(1+y)^2}{(x+y)(1+xy)}=1-\frac{y(1-x)^2}{(x+y)(1+x y)}$$
The second term is nonnegative and vanishes only if $x=1$ or $y=0$. The latter was already excluded above, while the former is part of the line of fixed points. So, unless we begin on the line of fixed points, one iteration always yields a point with $0<x'<1$. Hence we can assume without loss of generality that $0<x<1$.
With this in mind, some (not entirely obvious) algebra yields
$$\frac{1-x'}{1-x}=\frac{(1-x)y}{(x+y)(1+x y)}=1-\frac{x y (x+y+1)+x}{(x+y) (x y+1)}$$
Note that this expression is positive but bounded above by $1$. Hence $$0<1-x'<1-x\implies 0<x<x'<1$$
Iterating thus yields a increasing sequence of $x$'s which is bounded above by  $x^*=1$. Hence this sequence converges $x^*=1$, i.e., $x=1$ is indeed an attracting line of fixed points.

Warning: I don't do real analysis very often, so if I haven't stated the convergence clearly let me know...

First of all, the point you make about the domain: I was sloppy but yes, the physics of this model constrains the values of $(x,y)$ in $[0,1]^2$. That being said, I've read the answer and I'll give it a more thorough read tomorrow. Meanwhile, I'll ask a question about the philosophy of this answer: given that in the present case the linearization is unreliable, you had to find a "manual" method to determine the stability of this line. Is that the reason why you did so?

Regarding the convergence, bounded monotonic sequences converge to their sup/inf depending on whether they're increasing or decreasing. Probably one should prove that $x^\ast=1$ is the sup and not just a lower bound, but this answer really helps.

@Mr.Feynman More or less, yes. That said, the inequality route can be useful even in the case where the linear stability analysis is effective---namely, one can seek to derive quantitative statements about how fast convergence (or divergence) occurs.
